# How to identify menu item using xpath

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, automation, automated-tests

I need to identify the left side menu item using xpath. I tried as,

*`mat-tree-node[class$='ng-star-inserted'].findBy(text "Financial Management")`*

But it didn't workout and selenium not able to identify element. I tried to identify element using above syntax. But there is no luck.

***HTML Code:***

```
[![<mat-sidenav tabindex="-1" fixedtopgap="64" role="navigation" class="mat-drawer mat-sidenav ng-tns-c308-0 ng-trigger ng-trigger-transform mat-drawer-side mat-drawer-opened ng-star-inserted" style="transform: none; visibility: visible;">
   <div cdkscrollable="" class="mat-drawer-inner-container ng-tns-c308-0">
      <lx3-sidemenu class="nav no-print ng-tns-c308-0" _nghost-nyn-c360="">
         <nav _ngcontent-nyn-c360="" id="sideMenu" tabindex="-1">
            <mat-tree _ngcontent-nyn-c360="" role="tree" class="mat-tree cdk-tree tree">
               <mat-nested-tree-node _ngcontent-nyn-c360="" mattreenodetoggle="" class="cdk-tree-node cdk-nested-tree-node mat-nested-tree-node ng-star-inserted" role="treeitem" aria-level="1" aria-expanded="true">
                  <div _ngcontent-nyn-c360="" class="mat-tree-node item">
                     Dashboard 
                     <mat-icon _ngcontent-nyn-c360="" role="img" class="mat-icon notranslate mat-icon-rtl-mirror float-end material-icons mat-icon-no-color" aria-hidden="true" data-mat-icon-type="font"> expand_less </mat-icon>
                  </div>
                  <div _ngcontent-nyn-c360="" role="group" class="">
                     <mat-tree-node _ngcontent-nyn-c360="" mattreenodetoggle="" class="item cdk-tree-node mat-tree-node selected ng-star-inserted" role="treeitem" aria-level="2" aria-expanded="false"> Information </mat-tree-node>
                     <mat-tree-node _ngcontent-nyn-c360="" mattreenodetoggle="" class="item cdk-tree-node mat-tree-node ng-star-inserted" role="treeitem" aria-level="2" aria-expanded="false"> Locations </mat-tree-node>
                     <mat-tree-node _ngcontent-nyn-c360="" mattreenodetoggle="" class="item cdk-tree-node mat-tree-node ng-star-inserted" role="treeitem" aria-level="2" aria-expanded="false"> People </mat-tree-node>
                     <mat-tree-node _ngcontent-nyn-c360="" mattreenodetoggle="" class="item cdk-tree-node mat-tree-node ng-star-inserted" role="treeitem" aria-level="2" aria-expanded="false"> Staff </mat-tree-node>
                     <mat-tree-node _ngcontent-nyn-c360="" mattreenodetoggle="" class="item cdk-tree-node mat-tree-node ng-star-inserted" role="treeitem" aria-level="2" aria-expanded="false"> SystemProviders </mat-tree-node>
                     <mat-tree-node _ngcontent-nyn-c360="" mattreenodetoggle="" class="item cdk-tree-node mat-tree-node ng-star-inserted" role="treeitem" aria-level="2" aria-expanded="false"> Users </mat-tree-node>
                     <mat-tree-node _ngcontent-nyn-c360="" mattreenodetoggle="" class="item cdk-tree-node mat-tree-node ng-star-inserted" role="treeitem" aria-level="2" aria-expanded="false"> Laps </mat-tree-node>
                     <mat-tree-node _ngcontent-nyn-c360="" mattreenodetoggle="" class="item cdk-tree-node mat-tree-node ng-star-inserted" role="treeitem" aria-level="2" aria-expanded="false"> Delivery </mat-tree-node>
                     <mat-tree-node _ngcontent-nyn-c360="" mattreenodetoggle="" class="item cdk-tree-node mat-tree-node ng-star-inserted" role="treeitem" aria-level="2" aria-expanded="false"> Limits </mat-tree-node>
                     <mat-tree-node _ngcontent-nyn-c360="" mattreenodetoggle="" class="item cdk-tree-node mat-tree-node ng-star-inserted" role="treeitem" aria-level="2" aria-expanded="false"> Dashboards </mat-tree-node>
                     <!---->
                  </div>
               </mat-nested-tree-node>
               <mat-nested-tree-node _ngcontent-nyn-c360="" mattreenodetoggle="" class="cdk-tree-node cdk-nested-tree-node mat-nested-tree-node ng-star-inserted" role="treeitem" aria-level="1" aria-expanded="false">
                  <div _ngcontent-nyn-c360="" class="mat-tree-node item">
                     Reports 
                     <mat-icon _ngcontent-nyn-c360="" role="img" class="mat-icon notranslate mat-icon-rtl-mirror float-end material-icons mat-icon-no-color" aria-hidden="true" data-mat-icon-type="font"> expand_more </mat-icon>
                  </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
  //mat-tree-node[text()="Information"]
```